# List 2 not Printing out on console

Tags: c++, linked-list, cout

Code is supposed to print out List of numbers user entered as list 1, tell you how long the list is, let you search for a number, and then delete a number. Once the number is deleted its supposed to save it the to List 2 and then print out the numbers. The code works up until list 2. For some reason list 1 is either not making it to list 2 or its just not printing out list 2. I would appreciate assistance figuring out why this is happening.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "circularLinkedList.h"

using namespace std; 

void testCopyConstructor(circularLinkedList<int> oList);

int main()
{
    circularLinkedList<int> list1, list2;
    int num;

    cout << "Enter number ending with -999" << endl;
    cin >> num;

    while (num != -999)
    {
        list1.insertNode(num);
        cin >> num;
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "List 1: ";
    list1.print();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Length List 1: " << list1.length() << endl;

    cout << "Enter the number to be searched:  ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << endl;

    if (list1.search(num))
        cout << num << " found in the list" << endl;
    else
        cout << num << " not in the list" << endl;

    cout << "Enter the number to be deleted: ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << endl;

    list1.deleteNode(num);

    cout << "After deleting the node, "
         << "List 1: ";
    list1.print();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Length List 1: " << list1.length() << endl;

    list2 = list1;

    cout << "List 2: ";
    list2.print();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Length List 2: " << list2.length() << endl;

    testCopyConstructor(list1);

    cout << "List 1: ";
    list1.print();
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

void testCopyConstructor(circularLinkedList<int> oList)
{
}
```

circularLinkedList.h

```
#ifndef H_circularLinkedList
#define H_circularLinkedList

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert> 
using namespace std;

template <class Type> 
struct nodeType
{
  Type info;
  nodeType<Type> *link;
};

template <class Type>
class circularLinkedList
{
public:
    const circularLinkedList<Type>& operator=
                      (const circularLinkedList<Type>&); 
    //Overloads the assignment operator.
    void initializeList(); 
    //Initializes the list to an empty state.
      //Postcondition: first = nullptr, last = nullptr,
    //                count = 0
    bool isEmptyList();
    //Function to determine whether the list is empty. 
    //Postcondition: Returns true if the list is empty;
    //               otherwise, returns false.

    void print() const;

  int length();
    //Function to return the number of nodes in the 
    //list.
    //Postcondition: The value of count is returned.
    void destroyList();
    //Function to delete all the nodes from the list.
      //Postcondition: first = nullptr, last = nullptr, 
    //               count = 0
    Type front(); 
    //Function to return the first element of the list.
    //Precondition: The list must exist and must not be
    //empty.
      //Postcondition: If the list is empty, then the 
    //               program terminates; otherwise, 
      //               the first element of the list is 
    //               returned.
    Type back(); 
       //Function to return the last element of the
       //list.
    //Precondition: The list must exist and must not
    //be empty.
    //Postcondition: If the list is empty, then the 
    //               program terminates; otherwise,
    //               the last element of the list is 
    //               returned.

  bool search(const Type& searchItem);
    //Function to determine whether searchItem is in 
    //the list.
    //Postcondition: Returns true if searchItem is found
    //               in the list; otherwise, it returns
    //               false.

    void insertNode(const Type& newitem);

    void deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem);
      //Function to delete deleteItem from the list.
    //Postcondition: If found, the node containing 
      //               deleteItem is deleted from the 
    //                list, first points to the first
    //                node, and last points to the last 
    //                node of the updated list. 

    circularLinkedList(); 
      //Default constructor
    //Initializes the list to an empty state.
    //Postcondition: first = nullptr, last = nullptr, 
    //               count = 0 

    circularLinkedList(const circularLinkedList<Type>& otherList); 
         //Copy constructor

    ~circularLinkedList();   
      //Destructor
      //Deletes all the nodes from the list.
      //Postcondition: The list object is destroyed. 

protected:
    int count;    //variable to store the number of 
          //elements in the list
    nodeType<Type> *first; //pointer to the first node of 
                           //the list
    nodeType<Type> *last;  //pointer to the last node of 
                           //the list 
private:
    void copyList(const circularLinkedList<Type>& otherList); 
    //Function to make a copy of otherList.
    //Postcondition: A copy of otherList is created 
    //               and assigned to this list.
};

template <class Type>
bool circularLinkedList<Type>::isEmptyList()
{
    return (first == NULL);
  // function to determine if list is empty
}

template <class Type>
circularLinkedList<Type>::circularLinkedList() // default constructor
{
  first = nullptr;
  count = 0;
}

template <class Type>
void circularLinkedList<Type>::destroyList()
{
      nodeType<Type> *temp;
        nodeType<Type> *current = NULL;

        if (first != NULL)
        {
            current = first->link;
            first->link = NULL;
        }

        while (current != NULL)
        {
            temp = current;
            current = current->link;
            delete temp;
        }

        first = NULL;   //initialize last to NULL; first has already
                        //been set to NULL by the while loop
        count = 0;
  // function to destroy the list
}


template <class Type>
void circularLinkedList<Type>::initializeList()
{
  destroyList(); //if the list has any nodes, delete them
}

template <class Type>
int circularLinkedList<Type>::length()
{
  return count;
  // function to find the length of the list
}  // end length

template <class Type>
Type circularLinkedList<Type>::front()
{   
    assert(first != nullptr);
    return first->link->info; //return the info of the first node 
}//end front


template <class Type>
Type circularLinkedList<Type>::back()
{   
    assert(first != nullptr);
    return first->info; //return the info of the first node 
}//end back

template <class Type>
bool circularLinkedList<Type>::search(const Type& searchItem)
{
      nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list
        bool found = false;

        if (first != NULL)
        {
            current = first->link;

            while (current != first && !found)
            {
                if (current->info >= searchItem)
                    found = true;
                else
                    current = current->link;

                found = (current->info == searchItem);
            }
        }

        return found;
    }
    // function to search the list for a given item
//end search

template <class Type>
void circularLinkedList<Type>::insertNode(const Type& newitem)
{
      nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list
        nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent; //pointer just before current
        nodeType<Type> *newNode;  //pointer to create a node

        bool  found;

        newNode = new nodeType<Type>; //create the node

        newNode->info = newitem;   //store newitem in the node
        newNode->link = NULL;      //set the link field of the node
                                   //to NULL

        if (first == NULL)  //Case 1    e.g., 3
        {
            first = newNode;
            first->link = newNode;
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (newitem >= first->info)//e.g., 25 > 3
            {
                newNode->link = first->link;
                first->link = newNode;
                first = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                trailCurrent = first; //e.g., 1 < 3
                current = first->link;
                found = false;

                while (current != first && !found)
                    if (current->info >= newitem)
                        found = true;
                    else
                    {
                        trailCurrent = current;
                        current = current->link;
                    }

                trailCurrent->link = newNode;
                newNode->link = current;
            }

            count++;
        }
  // function to insert an item into the list
}//end insertNode

template <class Type>
void circularLinkedList<Type>::deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem)
{
   nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list
        nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent; //pointer just before current
        bool found;

        if (first == NULL)    //Case 1; list is empty.
            cout << "Can not delete from an empty list." << endl;
        else
        {
            found = false;
            trailCurrent = first;
            current = first->link;

            while (current != first && !found)
                if (current->info >= deleteItem)
                    found = true;
                else
                {
                    trailCurrent = current;
                    current = current->link;
                }

            if (current == first)
            {
                if (first->info == deleteItem)
                {
                    if (first == first->link)
                        first = NULL;
                    else
                    {
                        trailCurrent->link = current->link;
                        first = trailCurrent;
                    }
                    delete current;

                    count--;
                }
                else
                    cout << "The item to be deleted is not in the list." << endl;
            }
            else
                if (current->info == deleteItem)
                {
                    trailCurrent->link = current->link;
                    count--;
                    delete current;
                }
                else
                    cout << "Item to be deleted is not in the list." << endl;
        } 
  // function to delete an item from the list
} //end deleteNode


  //Overloading the stream insertion operator
template <class Type>
void  circularLinkedList<Type>::print() const
{
    nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list

        current = first->link;

        while (current != first) //while more data to print
        {
            cout << current->info << " ";
            current = current->link;
        }

        cout << first->info << " ";
  // function to print the list
}

template <class Type>
circularLinkedList<Type>::~circularLinkedList() // destructor
{
  destroyList(); 
}//end destructor


template <class Type>
void circularLinkedList<Type>::copyList
                    (const circularLinkedList<Type>& otherList) 
{
        first = NULL;
        copyList(otherList);
   // function to copy the list
}//end copyList

  //copy constructor
template<class Type>
circularLinkedList<Type>::circularLinkedList
                    (const circularLinkedList<Type>& otherList) 
{
  first = nullptr;

  copyList(otherList);

}//end copy constructor

  //overload the assignment operator
template <class Type>
const circularLinkedList<Type>& circularLinkedList<Type>::operator=
          (const circularLinkedList<Type>& otherList)
{ 
  if (this != &otherList) //avoid self-copy
  {
    copyList(otherList);
  }//end else

  return *this; 
}

#endif
```

Comment: *I would appreciate assistance figuring out why this is happening* -- Why not use the debugger that comes with your compiler toolset?

Comment: My debugger isn't giving out any errors. List 2 is simply not printing out on the console.

Comment: What do you think your `copyList` method should do? Why is it recursive?

Comment: @KristinaWoods -- A debugger doesn't "give out errors".  A debugger allows you to single-step through your program, watch variables, see the program flow, etc.  It allows you to see if the program takes a different path than what you expected, whether a variable or set of variables takes on values that aren't expected, etc..  A debugger has no idea what your program is intended to do, only you know that.

Comment: Nit, placing `using namespace std;` in a header will cause the entire namespace to be included in every file that includes the header. For your issue, what is happening with `first = NULL;` in `copyList`? Further, if `copyList` does nothing but `copyList(otherList);` how does that ever end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kristina, by having `copyList` call `copyList(otherList);` recursively, you are simply going to loop forever.

Take a step back. You have already default constructed `list1` and `list2` in `main()` when you created the instances of `circularLinkedList<int>`. So when you make the call `list2 = list1;` you are invoking the *copy assignment* member function. In your current code your copy assignment simply calls `copyList` (that in itself is fine) However, your `copyList` is a bit thin and doesn't do what you intend, e.g. containing only:

```
template <class Type>
void circularLinkedList<Type>::copyList
                    (const circularLinkedList<Type>& otherList) 
{
        first = NULL;
        copyList(otherList);      /* what happens when you get here? */
   // function to copy the list
}//end copyList
```

See the problem? You invoke `circularLinkedList<Type>::operator=`, which calls `circularLinkedList<Type>::copyList` and then you recursively call the same function over-and-over-and-over again.

(this is where you pay attention in the debugger -- after hitting `'s'` (step) in `copyList` only to see `first = NULL;` and find your back in `copyList` ready to execute `first = NULL;` again, something is wrong...)

However, overall, you are thinking correctly in terms of program structure and having the copy assignment invoke `copyList`, you just need to actually copy the list...

So what to do? You need to copy all nodes from the `otherList` reference to the new list. You can easily traverse `otherList`, just as you have done in `print()` directly above `copyList`, except instead of outputting each value, you need to `insertNode`.

(the fact that in `print()` you iterate beginning with `first->link` and not `first` is a bit peculiar for a circular list, but... that is more a naming issue here than anything else, the traversal works correctly)

Traversing `otherList` and calling `insertNode` in your `copyList` will work exactly the same as the traversal in `print()`. It can be something as simple as:

```
template <class Type>
void circularLinkedList<Type>::copyList
                    (const circularLinkedList<Type>& otherList) 
{
    nodeType<Type> *iter = otherList.first->link;

    while (iter != otherList.first) {
        this->insertNode (iter->info);
        iter = iter->link;
    }
    this->insertNode (iter->info);

} //end copyList
```

(you can use `current` instead of `iter` if that makes more sense to you, but I find `iter` more descriptive of what I'm doing with the reference, but that is just a personal preference).

Now your *copy assignment* and *copy constructor* should work and be invoked properly. You don't need `testCopyConstructor` at all in `main()`. To test both the *copy assignment* and *copy constructor*, you can simply add another instance of list in main that would invoke the copy constructor as opposed to the copy assignment, e.g.

```
    list2 = list1;           /* copy assignment called */

    cout << "List 2: ";
    list2.print();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Length List 2: " << list2.length() << endl;

    cout << "List 1: ";
    list1.print();
    cout << endl;

    circularLinkedList<int> list3 (list2);   /* copy constructor called */
    cout << "\nList 3: ";
    list3.print();
    cout << "\n";
```

**Example Use/Output**

After putting it altogether, you should be able to execute your code as intended, e.g.:

```
$ ./bin/llcirmain
Enter number ending with -999
1 2 3 4 5 -999

List 1: 1 2 3 4 5
Length List 1: 5
Enter the number to be searched:  4

4 found in the list
Enter the number to be deleted: 3

After deleting the node, List 1: 1 2 4 5
Length List 1: 4
List 2: 1 2 4 5
Length List 2: 4
List 1: 1 2 4 5

List 3: 1 2 4 5
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. (and think about removing `using namespace std;` from the header file, you don't want to include the complete standard namespace in ever source file that may use your header).

Comment: Thanks David. Unfortunately debugging is currently an issue for me. This is an assignment done on an website with its own debugger which doesn't do anything other then give errors, bad errors at that. I've tried doing assignments in visual studios but code that works fine there fails the online test. Its been a bit frustrating, especially for a beginner like me. Thank you for the detailed explanation really helped on both this assignment and another one.  I can't actually make changes to the main, but I was able to  get it working once I understood the issue.

Comment: Oh, oh, don't throw me in the VS briar-patch, p l e a s e.... Debugging is just one of those things (kind of like coding itself), you just have to stumble through enough times, and you figure out what to look for, and how to shorten the time it takes to get there. I am spoiled, I compile everything from the command line (larger projects with Makefiles, etc..), but then I have `gdb` to fall back on. Like most tools on Linux (`vi`, `emacs`, etc..) it takes making friends with, but you eat a whale - one bite at a time. Good luck with your coding.